# how to override gorm delete method for testing?

Tags: grails, integration-testing

I am writing a simple integration test where i intend to simulate  delete failure.

The controller simply pulls the record from database and deletes it as shown below.

```
def deleteItem(id){


    def item = Item.get(id)

    item.delete()

}
```

Now, i want to simulate delete failure with following code

```
void testDeleteItem_FailDeleteFlushSaveFail(){


    Item.metaClass.delete = { Map params ->

        throw new ValidationException("Failed!!")

    }



    def model = controller.deleteItem(mp.id)


    assertEquals controller.flash.message, "Sorry an error occured when deleting!!"



    GroovySystem.metaClassRegistry.removeMetaClass(Item.class)



}
```

But the test fails because the method is not replaced. i.e exception is not thrown on delete. I am guessing the problem is in my metaclass formulation. How can i make it so that exception is thrown when delete is called? I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you should use

```
Item.metaClass.delete = {

        throw new ValidationException("Failed!!")

    }
```

rather than

```
Item.metaClass.delete = { Map params ->

        throw new ValidationException("Failed!!")

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, I don't think the question should have been down-voted.. It is a valid question for a scenario in which you are wanting to test how your program reacts to a failure.

There are a few things wrong here:

- Domain.delete does not throw validationExceptions. Also ValidationExceptions are constructed with two arguments (String msg, Errors error). You would need to add a custom error to your domain class and pass the domain class in. Again this doesn't make sense for delete because who needs to validate the object on delete?
  Not sure what version you're running but here is the docs for 2.5.1 ([Grails 2.5.1 docs](http://docs.grails.org/2.5.1/guide/GORM.html) -see 7.3.2 Deleting Objects)

  def p = Person.get(1)
  try {
      p.delete(flush: true)
  }
  catch (org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
      flash.message = "Could not delete person ${p.name}"
      redirect(action: "show", id: p.id)
  }
- Secondly, delete(failOnError: true). I'm not sure that does anything at all. Instead you should surround your delete method in a try catch and use the flush: true option.

  ```
  try{
      item.delete(flush:true)
  }catch(DataIntegrityViolationException e){
      flash.message = "Sorry an error occurred when deleting!!"
  }
  ```
- Thirdly, where is mp.id coming from? Are we missing a portion of your test file. If not, your test appears to rely on data that is already existing. Even in an integration test it is wise to create your data separately for each test in some way to prevent test contamination and failed tests due to missing data.
- Finally, I have not been able to properly metaClass the Domain Class itself in my integration tests... so I would recommend you metaClass the domain instance in your test. Here is an example of that:

**MetaClass Domain Instance method:**

```
//creating test data
def item = new Item(name: 'testName')

def model = controller.deleteItem(item.id)

item.metaClass.delete = {Map params ->
    throw new DataIntegrityViolationException('Some error message')
}

assertEquals controller.flash.message, "Sorry an error occurred when deleting!!"
```

**Edit 1 Note**
I forgot to include the 'Map params ->' In the metaClass closure. (might not be required in all versions of grails due to the differences in how these methods are compiled through out the versions)

Answer (score -1):

Try that using:

```
Item.metaClass.'static'.delete = { Map params ->
    throw new ValidationException("Failed!!")
}
```